# Angular Routing not Working (Error: The Site Cannot Be Found)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

After creating a new app in NX workspace, I am using two components at the moment. Homepage and Product List Page. When I try to create router links, the site displays the error that "Site Cannot Be Reached"

Here is my app module ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
//import { appRoutes } from './app.routes';
import { HomePageComponent } from './pages/home-page/home-page.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from './pages/product-list/product-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent}, 
  { path:'products', component: ProductListComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    //RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking' }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  
})


export class AppModule {}
```

And naturally I declared the correct path on my app component (root) page:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Try `{ path: '', component: HomePageComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},`

Comment: Thank you. The issue went away after I ran the code after closing everything and enusring I am in the right directory to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes object doesn't have a default route so when you open your app in browser the URL is "http://localhost:4200/" and this route is not in the list of your routes.

The solution for this problem is to change routes object to this one:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'home', component: HomePageComponent},
      { path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent},
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    ]
```

I made these changes in routes object:

1. Changed the route to your home page from '' to 'home'.
2. Added a default route (fallback route) at the end of the routes object.

When you are using angular routing, you must define a default route like this:

- The path must be "" (an empty string).
- Use redirectTo property with value of your main page (in your case it is '/home')
- Use pathMatch property with value of 'full' that any route which is not defined in routes object, be redirected to your home page.

*Tip: For a good practice, i recommend you to create a 404 page component and when a path does not exist redirect users to that component instead of your home page. Also put a navigation menu there for your available routes.*

Comment: Thank you Amir, this is a good fix but before trying your answer, I tried building everything again as I suspected there was an issue with my directories since I am using NX workspace, so before trying your fix, issue got resolved. But this is a great and useful fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you wrote, I just need to know that the feature In which component did you put the **router-outlet**?

You should put the **router-outlet** attribute inside **app.component.html**

I tried your code in a raw project
And I got a complete answer

I hope I have been able to help

Comment: Thank you for taking out the time. Turns out there was issue with NX workspace, I was probably in the wrong directory. I ran it after closing everything and making sure I was in the right directory, and everything works now. Thanks!